# Next.JS SSG broken with Redux Persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-persist

I am trying to get SSG working along with Redux Persist but sadly `<div id="__next"></div>` is always empty even when I use Redux Persist.

Expected: (Without Redux Persist) - Works perfectly, the data appears in the DOM from the store.
[image]

Getting: (With Redux persist) - Persists perfectly, but __next div is always empty therefore making it non-SEO friendly and voids the point of doing SSG.
[image]

I am using `getStaticProps` to fetch the data and dispatch actions on the store within getStaticProps.
My getStaticProps implementation with and without redux persist is of the form:

```
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(
  async ({ params, store }) => {
store.dispatch({type:"SOME_TYPE",payload:{}})
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I have encountered the same problem now. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, looks like the creator of Next.js addressed it here - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16389

Has to do with the way redux-persist is handling stuff.

Comment: Well spotted! Thanks Rahul! I have also created an issue directly for their with-redux-persist example and it was closed by Next.js team as Redux-persist problem.